# Article title without the definite article before the word best

Tags: definite-article, headlinese

I have learned that before phrases like the best, the latest, the smallest, etc, I have to use the definite article because the best is only one thing. Is this title of an article correct?

> Shopping Guide for Best Women's Running Shoes

If I would write that, I would write `for the Best Women's Running Shoes`

Comment: Titles and headlines use  '[tag:headlinese]', a style which eliminates as many uninformative words as possible so the headline can be displayed as large as possible.

Comment: @StoneyB you mean as small as possible? ;) thanks

Comment: Fewer words and characters means the typeface can be much larger in the space allotted.

Comment: @StoneyB ok, I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.  As a headline of an article, *"Best Women's Running Shoes"* would be fine.  As StoneyB says in his comment (and in the linked answer), "headline" English often eliminated short and unnecessary words to save space.

However, *"Shopping Guide for Best Women's Running Shoes"* sounds awkward to me, and I would include the definite article. I'm not sure why this is, but it's possibly because the second part is a phrase modifying "Shopping Guide".

Three letters (four counting the space) can't really hurt, and it flows better.